# Are money rocks shared?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

If I farm a [money rock](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Money_Rock) with my Mayor character, can my boyfriend use the same rock, later during the same day, on his character for money as well? Or will a new random rock be his money rock?

Or will he be left out in the cold (because he can't afford a house)?

[image: Laughing it up as I rake in the dough]

Comment: I'm fairly sure each player gets their own random money rock.  That's the way it worked in past games.  I will have my wife test this (she has a character for herself and our daughter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each player gets their own random money rock.  I tested this to be sure.